# For a set $B\subset [0,1]$, how to show that If $\nu(B)=0$, then $\mu(B)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

Define two measures on the real line as
$$
\mu(A)=\int_A 1_{[0,1]}(x)dx
$$
and
$$
\nu(A)=\int_A x^2 1_{[0,1]}(x)dx
$$
for all Borel sets $A$. Show that $\mu$  and $\nu$  are equivalent.

---

For all sets $A$ outside $[0,1]$, we have $\mu(A)=\mu(A)=0$. But for a set $B\subset [0,1]$, how to show that $\mu(B)=0$, then $\nu(B)=0$? Also, how to show the converse statement? If $\nu(B)=0$, then $\mu(B)=0$?

Comment: Have you tried establishing an analogue of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: In one direction, you can show one measure is always greater than or equal to the other.

Comment: @leslietownes How to use this inequality? Can you give details? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure then $\mu(A)=\lambda(A\cap[0,1])$. Thus $\mu(B)=0$ means that $B$ is of Lebesgue measure zero on $[0,1]$ and thus the integral for $\nu(B)$ should be zero no matter what your integrand is.

Comment: Why $\nu(B)=0$ for a Leb null set $B$?

Comment: How about the inverse statement? If $\nu(B)=0$, then $\mu(B)=0$?

Comment: @Hermi The inverse is basically that since $x^2$ is positive a.e. if you get $\mu(B)>0$ then the integral of $x^2$ over $B$ must be positive, which is a contradiction. For your first question you can eg. note that $\nu(B)\leq \int_B 1dx=\lambda(B)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused about the second question. If $\nu(B)=0$, then $\int_B x^2 1_{[0,1]}dx=0$. If $\mu(B)=\int_B 1dx>0$, why $\int_B x^2 1_{[0,1]}dx>0$?

Comment: @Hermi If $B$ has positive measure, it contains a compact subset also of positive measure. Now on this compact set $x^2$ has its minimum $m$, which is positive. Thus the integral is larger than $m\mu(B)>0$.